# How do i specify X-Headers for outgoing emails in Microsoft Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook-addin, email-headers, sendgrid

I need to include custom headers in my outgoing emails.

I'm using Microsoft Outlook 2010 and SendGrid SMTP server.

In particular, i want to specify a unique tracking ID on each mail using SendGrid's *X-SMTPAPI* header.

My Approach:

I am build an Outlook Add-In that will intercept outgoing emails and add the required headers
*Outlook.Application* object has an *ItemSend* event that serves this purpose.

How do i use ***Mail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty*** to set the custom headers?
I am unable to find the correct header identifier that points to x-headers, or that will allow me set custom headers.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReliefJet Essentials' [Outlook rules integration](http://www.reliefjet.com/Product/Features/Integration#Rules) allows that. You just create an outgoing rule and select ReliefJet Essentials' *Set Header Value* tool as a custom action. That's all!

Comment: this solution works really well. They also provide simple macros so you can have dynamic values.

Comment: Strangely, this doesnt work for me - the rule runs, and can perform other actions, but does not add a header.  Some of the documentation for ReliefJet seems to indicate that possibly it doesnt work with send rules in the current version?

Comment: Integration with outgoing rules works for Outlook 2010 and below. Outlook 2013 doesn't provide this feature.

Comment: It should be noted that this is a commercial product that [has to be paid](http://www.reliefjet.com/Purchase) for.

Answer (score 4):

I am able to add an X-header. It was tricky to find the GUID

```
const string SP_INTERNETHEADERS = "{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/";
const string internetheaderSchema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/" + SP_INTERNETHEADERS;
string mailproperty = internetheaderSchema + XHeader;
MailItem olmail = ThisAddIn._Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
olmail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(mailproperty, value);
olmail.Save();
```