# Adding headers to outgoing emails using WinRT

Tags: email, windows-runtime, email-headers

I would like to write email client app using WinRT API that would send emails with custom headers (x-headers). Content of the header will depend on content of email. Something like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803977/how-do-i-specify-x-headers-for-outgoing-emails-in-microsoft-outlook-2010).

I did not find any methods or properties of the [EmailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmessage.aspx) to do it. Is there a way to register message processor down the email send pipeline (if there is a pipeline)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, modifying headers for email messages is not possible in WinRT and there is no endpoint you could have that will allow you to "intercept" the messages to modify them.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. Do you have a lot of experience with WinRT? If you are correct, and MS is not actively working on update and better documentation, it makes WinRT pretty useless. X  headers is not the only problem I encountered and i suspect there are even more. I do not expect any API to be complete, but it should be "bridgable" to other APIs, i.e. it should expose data that one can use say in Win32.it would be nice to hear from MS about its plans for WinRT.

Comment: I work with WinRT from its beginning and I agree that there are some points that are really a pain....
If you are developping a LOB app (e.g. an enterprise app that will be side loaded), you can use a Brokered Component to access all the features of the .NET Framework from your WinRT app.